# Every subsequence sum of size 'k'

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcBDb.jpg)How to obtain number of subsequences with minimum sum given that size of subsequence is exactly 'k' and there should be no subsequence having less than that sum? Ex input  n=4,k=2

1 2 3 4
Output:
1

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific issue are you running into?

Comment: I am obtaining all the subsequences of size k and tgen storing every sum into an array and then counting the minimum subsequences but i am getting runtime error

Comment: @Priti "_but i am getting runtime error_" What runtime error? Running which code? As far as we are concerned (based on the information provided in the question), there is no code.

Comment: Make a [mcve] with the input and expected output.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius i have added the picture of my code

Comment: @Priti Why picture? Please provide [mcve] **as text**. The question should be self-contained, and be understandable, without links to 3rd party websites. Especially, if it is just text.

Comment: Whats the point of competing in an online competition then? Ask for help after you have tried everything and the competition is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic programming solution.

1. create dp[n][k + 1].
2. dp[i][j]: for arr a[0...i], the minimum possible sum of any sub sequence of length k.
3. dp[0][0] = 0, dp[0][1] = a[0], dp[0][i] = INT_MAX for i > 1, dp[i][0] = INT_MAX for i>0.
4. dp[i][j] = min(dp[i-1][j], dp[i-1][j-1] + a[i]) for i>0 and j>0

ans: min(d[0...n-1][k])

O(n^2) time and space solution. Time complexity can be brought down to O(n).